# error pushing to heroku; heroku is trying to install something related to sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to push an app to heroku and am getting the below error message.  i've seen some of the other posts on this topic and I don't see away to fix it.  i don't have sqlite3 referenced anywhere in the application nor do I have it as a gem in my own system.  thoughts?

```
Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.0.pre
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
   Installing rake (0.9.2.2)
   Installing i18n (0.6.0)
   Installing multi_json (1.3.6)
   Installing activesupport (3.2.3)
   Installing builder (3.0.0)
   Installing activemodel (3.2.3)
   Installing erubis (2.7.0)
   Installing journey (1.0.4)
   Installing rack (1.4.1)
   Installing rack-cache (1.2)
   Installing rack-test (0.6.1)
   Installing hike (1.2.1)
   Installing tilt (1.3.3)
   Installing sprockets (2.1.3)
   Installing actionpack (3.2.3)
   Installing mime-types (1.19)
   Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
   Installing treetop (1.4.10)
   Installing mail (2.4.4)
   Installing actionmailer (3.2.3)
   Installing arel (3.0.2)
   Installing tzinfo (0.3.33)
   Installing activerecord (3.2.3)
   Installing activeresource (3.2.3)
   Installing coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
   Installing execjs (1.4.0)
   Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
   Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2)
   Installing json (1.7.3) with native extensions
   Installing rdoc (3.12)
   Installing thor (0.14.6)
   Installing railties (3.2.3)
   Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
   Installing jquery-rails (2.0.2)
   Using bundler (1.2.0.pre)
   Installing rails (3.2.3)
   Installing sass (3.1.20)
   Installing sass-rails (3.2.5)
   Installing sqlite3 (1.3.6) with native extensions
   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for sqlite3.h... no
   sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
   or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
   location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
   details.  You may need configuration options.
   Provided configuration options:
   --with-opt-dir
   --without-opt-dir
   --with-opt-include
   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
   --with-opt-lib
   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
   --with-make-prog
   --without-make-prog
   --srcdir=.
   --curdir
   --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
   --with-sqlite3-dir
   --without-sqlite3-dir
   --with-sqlite3-include
   --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
   --with-sqlite3-lib
   --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
   --enable-local
   --disable-local
   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_epqv5l1a15kp/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_epqv5l1a15kp/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
   An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.
   Failed to install gems via Bundler.
   Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
   http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-for-development 
   Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

My gem file looks like;

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
group :development, :test do
gem "pg", "~> 0.14.0"  
gem "rspec", "~> 2.11.0"
end
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
group :production do
gem "pg", "~> 0.14.0"
end
```

and my gemfile.lock looks like;

```
    GEM  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.3)
      actionpack (= 3.2.3)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.3)
      activemodel (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.1)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.2)
    activemodel (3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.3)
      activemodel (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.3)
      activemodel (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
    activesupport (3.2.3)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.7.3)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.19)
    multi_json (1.3.6)
    pg (0.14.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.3)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.3)
      actionpack (= 3.2.3)
      activerecord (= 3.2.3)
      activeresource (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.3)
    railties (3.2.3)
      actionpack (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec (2.11.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.11.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.11.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.11.0)
    rspec-core (2.11.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.11.1)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.3)
    rspec-mocks (2.11.1)
    sass (3.1.20)
    sass-rails (3.2.5)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.1.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.33)
    uglifier (1.2.6)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  jquery-rails
  pg (~> 0.14.0)
  rails (= 3.2.3)
  rspec (~> 2.11.0)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you have not committed your Gemfile.lock. What does `git status` tell you? Alternatively, try `git add .` then try `git status` again.

Comment: that worked.  such a crazy detail to overlook.  i ensured everything was added to the commit and then commited, repushed to heroku.  thanks!

Comment: btw, what is a your twitter/email, i'm kind of curious what the ruby community in SG is like.  I speak mandarin and have had some good times there, would like to look for dev/biz collaboration opportunities.